# Rules for capitalizing adjectives after "etwas, nichts..."?

Tags: noun, adjective, nominalization

Why does one write "nichts Gutes", "etwas Besseres" and so on. The rules imply they are nouns. [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gutes)  says they obbey an ,,adjektivischer Deklination", there is no plural for them, etc.

> But can one substantivize any adjective this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can substantivize any adjective that way: Nichts Schönes, alles Gute, etwas Herrliches - yet, there's an exception: "anderes". It's "etwas/nichts/manch anderes", used without a capital letter. As a general rule you can say that any adjective which follows those words AND doesn't explicitly refer to another word is substantivized:

> Ich habe manch *Schönes* erlebt.

but

> Ich habe manch *schönes Haus* gesehen.

Comment: Ich wusste nicht über "anderes". Danke!

Comment: Gern geschehen.

Comment: I have to disagree related to "anderes". According to *Deutsche Rechtschreibung: Regeln und Wörterverzeichnis*, §58, E4: "Wenn der Schreibende zum Ausdruck bringen will, dass das Zahladjektiv substantivisch gebraucht ist, kann er es nach § 57(1) auch großschreiben, zum Beispiel: Sie strebte etwas ganz Anderes an." (see also: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/gross-und-kleinschreibung#K77 )

Answer (score 3):

You can always substantivize adjectives or adverbs if you can:

- either append "-heit" or "-keit" ("sauber" - "Sauberkeit")
- or place a noun marker in front of it ("gut" - "das Gute")

Comment: @c.p. Only „das Rote“.

Comment: @c.p. "die Röte" would also be possible

Comment: After the tinny edit of the answer, I undersand now what you mean. However, the answer seems cyclic. Now the question is "when can you either append "-heit" or "-keit" OR or place a noun marker in front of it?