# Difference between feminine (“die Röte”) and neuter colors (“das Rote”)

Tags: difference, adjective, noun, gender

I’ve seen [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/6489/), in the discussion after an the answer by sedden, that two ways exist to substantivize a color (perhaps that also applies to more adjectives).

**Is there any difference in meaning (or any aspect) between the feminine color and the neutral one?**

For instance “das Rote” and “die Röte”. As one can see from the [*Duden*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Roete), the latter is a completely conventional noun while the first one is obeys an adjectival declension *(adjectivische Deklination)* and other features of an adjective remain in it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is a subtle and difficult-to-grasp difference and there even is a third possibility.

First of all, a neutral form can be used for something in this colour:

> das Weiße des Auges – the white part of the eye
>
> das Schwarze der Zielscheibe – the black part of a target; the bullseye

The second neutral form (note the different inflection without -e) can be used to refer to a specific shade of a colour or light of that colour:

> Ich mag das Weiß der Tapete. – I like the wallpaper’s white (that exact shade of white).
>
> Das Weiß der Tapete blendete. – The wallpaper’s white was glaring (e.g., because the rest of the room was dark).
>
> Ich mag das Blau ihrer Augen. – I like the blue of her eyes.

The female form refers to a tint of a colour, the extent to which something is tinted in a colour or the fact that something is in a colour. In the English translation usually -ness is appended:

> Die Weiße seiner Haut war beunruhigend. – The whiteness of his skin was alarming. (Note that usually *Blässe* is used instead of *Weiße.*)
>
> die Schwärze der Nacht – the blackness of the night
>
> Röte stieg ihr ins Gesicht. – Her face turned red (she blushed).

Finally, the female form sometimes refers to a dye of that colour:

> Druckerschwärze – printer’s ink
>
> Malerweiße – white dye used to paint walls

I hope I did not miss anything.

Comment: With some bot not all colours there is the ending *-e* to make a difference with or without change of gender: *das Schwarz - das Schwarze - die Schwärze*, *das Blau - das Blaue - die Bläue*, *das Gelb - das Gelbe*.

Comment: @Mac: Thinking about it once more, I agree that this example was not such a good one. Though I would say that there is more to *Abendrot vs. Abendröte* than just oldfashionedness, it certainly is confusing in this context.

Answer (score 4):

When I first red... read the question, my spontaneous answer was this:

die **Röte/Bläue/Schwärze/Grünheit/Gelbheit.**.. feels like 
**the redness/blueness/greeness**...

and while I know that most of those are not actually English words, I think they get the vibe of the female colors versions across.